# How to use the position relative in angular

Tags: html, css, angular, drop-down-menu, dropdown

i have this dropdown inside another one, but i want to put this second dropdown to the right, i'm trying use position relative like this in the scss

```
.bloco2{
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 200px;
}
```

but it remains in the same place, and the margin-top works

```
        <div ngbDropdown>
          <li ngbDropdownToggle>
            <a class="dropdown-item">
              <i class="bi bi-box mx-2"></i>
              Meus Editais
            </a>
          </li>
          <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1" class="bloco2">
            <button ngbDropdownItem>•  Lista de Meus Editais</button>
            <button ngbDropdownItem>•  Propostas Cadastradas para o Edital</button>
            <button ngbDropdownItem>•  Avaliação Propostas do Edital</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try using `position:absolute;` in combination with `left:xxx;top:yyy;` instead.

When an element is positioned using position:absolute, it is then positioned relative to the nearest parent element that has position:relative or position:absolute.

So in your case, I would recommend adding an identifier (class or id) to the parent element and setting its position as relative. Then change your bloco2 class to be absolute.

```
<div ngbDropdown id="parentElement">
```

Then apply style:

```
#parentElement {position:relative;}
.bloco2 {position:absolute; left:200px; top:100px}
```

Note: the above is simply to illustrate the effect of using absolute positioning. You will need to fine tune the correct values yourself.

Also, your html elements are not valid. Your < li > tags should sit within < ul > or < ol > tags not a < div >. Its common practice to house menu items like this in an unordered list like shown here:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36811224/why-do-navigation-bars-in-html5-as-lists#:~:text=By%20using%20a%20ul%20%2C%20it's,all%20available%20navigation%20links%20and](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36811224/why-do-navigation-bars-in-html5-as-lists#:%7E:text=By%20using%20a%20ul%20%2C%20it%27s,all%20available%20navigation%20links%20and)

**EDIT**
Please see very simple example below:

```
<html>
<body>
<style>
  ul {width:100px}
  .level1 {position:relative;background-color:#f00;}
  .level1 ul {position:absolute;z-index:99;left:100px;}
  .level2 {background-color:#0f0;}
</style>
<ul>
  <li class="level1">Item 1</li>
  <li class="level1">Item 2</li>
  <li class="level1">Item 3
    <ul>
      <li class="level2">Sub item 1</li>
      <li class="level2">Sub item 2</li>
      <li class="level2">Sub item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="level1">Item 4</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

This demonstrates how the unordered list < ul > is absolutely positioned, relative to its parent < li > tag.

Comment: Thanks for the attention Dean O'Brien, unfortunately that didn't work, but thanks for the tips, when I get it fixed I'll answer you here how I did it

Comment: Hi Gabriel, I have updated my answer with a simple example showing how to absolutely position something relative to another element.